# Optimize the selection with max() or min() condition query in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, max, amazon-redshift, min

Now I have a table which looks like this:

```
VisitorId   VisitId   visittime   hitNumber    Pagetitle  EventCategory
1001        0001      2017-12-31    1          Product    scroll down 
1001        0001      2017-12-31    2          Product    click   
1001        0001      2017-12-31    3          Product    Fill info
1002        0002      2017-12-31    1          Homepage   Download
1002        0002      2017-12-31    2          Contact    /
1002        0002      2017-12-31    3          Check out  Shopping cart
1002        0002      2017-12-31    4          Check out  Abandon shopping cart
```

What I have to do is, to extract always the last action that the visitor do in our website.

My currently solution is to split the table into 2, Take the maximum number of hits and join back with remaining infromation i.e

```
Select 
    visitorid, 
    VisitId, 
    visittime, 
    MAX(a.hitnumber) action_hit, 
    b.Pagetitle, 
    b.EventCategory
from 
    table a
left join (
   Select
      visitorid, 
      visitId, 
      visittime,
      hitnumber, 
      Pagetitle, 
      EventCategory
   FROM 
      table ) b ON a.visitorid = b.visitorid AND a.visitId = b.visitId 
   AND a.visittime = b.visittime
GROUP BY 1,2,3,5,6
HAVING MAX(a.hitnumber) = b.hitnumber
```

But I am curious if there is any other alternative that I can make the script shorter and with the same effect.

Does anyone have some idea for that? Many thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by visitor_id, visit_id order by hit_number desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```